# Use attribute of all filtered features of one layer as label in the Print composer

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, print-composer, filter, atlas

Is it possible to filter some features in one layer and use those filtered features as labels in the Print composer of another layer?

I am trying to make an atlas. I have two layers, one which has the province data, and another which has the city data. Both these layers have 9-digit codes; the city data has something like `140106000`, while the province has something like `140100000`. I would like to filter the features in the city layer to match the code as `1401`. All features in the city layer with codes that match `1401` I would like to display their "name" attributes in the print composer (so that all filtered city names appear in the print composer, like a list).

I do not know of any way to do this.

Comment: Do you want them to appear in the legend,  or in a table in the map itself?

Comment: @wingnut I would prefer that the names appear either in a plain list (unordered/ordered) or table.

Comment: But specifically on the map or in the legend object? It makes a difference. You can make a table from any layer on the map. Putting things in the legend is much harder. To filter, just filter a layer in the main QGS window,  then in the Composer,  make a table from it. The filter would just be an expression based on the first 4 characters of the code.

Answer (score 1):

My solution would be to do a table that contain the list of the cities filtered.

You have a province layer which you want to do atlas with (make a map for each province) and a city layer you want for each atlas page to filter and list only the one linked with your province. Both layer have an attribute (i will name it `9digit_code`) like you described.

1. In the print composer activate atlas with your province layer. Select your map item and check `controlled by atlas` and then activate atlas to check it work well.
2. Add a table intem in the composer with your city layer. Choose the column you want to keep, if you want to be shown as a list you can keep only one column and show no grid. The result will be a list or a table of all the features in the city layer.
3. In your table properties activate the option `filter with` and add this formula : `left((attributes(@atlas_feature) ['9digit_code']),4) = left ("9digit_code", 4)`.

Note : You may adapt the name of your field in the two layer, the first is the name in your atlas layer the second is the name in your city layer. The content of your list could be adapted with formula to show concatenation of your city name and population divided by 1000 for example.

PS : If you want to set the position of your table in the page you may find advice here : [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/394440/adapt-attribute-table-qgis-legend-from-bottom/394447#394447)